# detect domains from text with regular expression

Tags: regex, url, text, dns, find

I've been finding url from text by preg_match with this pattern `/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/`

Any further solutions for detecting domains instead of url?  May be with a list of top-level domain like this:
**.asia .biz .cat .com .net .edu .gov .info .com.eu .com.au**

//Edit

For example I have a paragraph like this:

**Hello world. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22112284/edit**

And I want to find this domain **stackoverflow.com** in that text.

Comment: TLDs may have much more than 3 characters, see: http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the domain, then just stop at a slash. In fact, you've got it there already, just shorten it. I also added another spot the the end, as there are some wierd top level domains out there (`.info`, `.mobi` for instance)

```
(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}
```

Comment: I'm sorry that my question is not so clear. I've just edited it. 

I've also tried your suggestion and it doesn't work.

Comment: You might start with this regex, and then just filter out the protocol portion. Just a thought.

Comment: In case that the text doesn't contain those prefix HTTP:// or HTTP://WWW it is not gonna work at all. So i'm thinking about detecting domains by those top-level domains. They might be listed in an array. But I can't find a way to make it work with preg_match.